# adjusting Kalman estimates for no data

Tags: estimation, kalman-filter

I have a kalman filter like set up, when I get the current value of an observable process, and update my estimate of the state variable with it.

However, my observations are non-uniform in time, and I am trying to add the logic, that if the last observation was really long ago, I should forget about it, and use an a priori estimate X.

I can just switch to X, if time since the last observation is > T. But I was hoping to put in some general setting, which will be consistent with the Kalman filter logic. Does anyone have suggestions/references for it?

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are observing $V_t, V_{t-1}, \ldots$ to update the system state $X_t$, why not observe $(V_t, V_{t-1})$ jointly and update the state only when $V_t = V_{t-1}$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your suggestion. Say, I have a stream of observations: 3 at t_1, 5 at t_2, 3 at t_3, 5 at t_4 - are you suggesting to ignore all of those?

Comment: And are you directly observing a state here? For instance, you *observe* 3 at time 1, but does that mean the *state* is 3 at time 1... the observations need not be the states, you could be observing acceleration in a vehicle and predicting its location on a road for instance.

Comment: Yes, for simplicity, assume, that we are observing the state.

Comment: Then my example would not yield any valid state for the observations you present.

Answer (score 0):

If the Kalman filter-like model includes a covariance for the error-states, and if this covariance is being propagated in time such that it grows in the absence of new measurements, then a natural solution to the problem is to periodically check the trace of the error covariance against a ceiling threshold.  If the threshold is exceeded we assume the filter has lost all useful information about the state, and that the state estimate should be reset to the a-priori value.  Since the KF is usually a linearized approximation for a non-linear problem there is good reason to question the usefulness of the information stored in the covariance if the state error covariance is large.